# why two processes can still use a FIFO to communicate after the FIFO been deleted?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fifo

I've made a FIFO using the *mkfifo* command,and created two processes to use the FIFO to communicate.But I've found that while the processes using the FIFO,I removed the FIFO,and the two processes can still even use the non-existed FIFO to send data,why?

Answer (score 4):

The object has been removed from the filesystem, but just as with all other files it will continue to exist until all open file descriptors on/from it are closed.